# compute-sanitizer reports both "Address is out of bounds" and "is inside the nearest allocation"

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cublas

I'm having trouble interpreting this CUDA error message. I've used `compute-sanitizer` to track it down to a memory access in a particular kernel, a libcublas batch matrix multiplication. I don't understand the error, because it reports both "Address is out of bounds" and "Address is inside the nearest allocation". If it's inside an allocation, how is it out of bounds? What's actually going wrong here?

```
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4 bytes
=========     at 0x18e0 in void gemv2N_kernel<int, int, float, float, float, float, (int)128, (int)8, (int)4, (int)4, (int)1, (bool)0, cublasGemvParams<cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<const float>, cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<const float>, cublasGemvTensorStridedBatched<float>, float>>(T13)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,137)
=========     Address 0x7fd8c0000224 is out of bounds
=========     and is inside the nearest allocation at 0x7fd8aa000000 of size 503316480 bytes
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame: [0x209e4a]
=========                in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
=========     Host Frame: [0x21caf9b]
=========                in /usr/local/cuda-11.5.0/lib64/libcublasLt.so.11
=========     Host Frame: [0x2224d18]
=========                in /usr/local/cuda-11.5.0/lib64/libcublasLt.so.11
=========     Host Frame: [0x8c257c]
=========                in /usr/local/cuda-11.5.0/lib64/libcublasLt.so.11
=========     Host Frame: [0x8c7717]
=========                in /usr/local/cuda-11.5.0/lib64/libcublasLt.so.11
=========     Host Frame: [0x67d937]
=========                in /usr/local/cuda-11.5.0/lib64/libcublasLt.so.11
=========     Host Frame:cublasLtSSSMatmul [0x6a3e03]
<a bunch of stack trace of my calling code omitted>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I did track this down to accessing an array with an invalid index. So, I still don't understand the error message, but if anyone else runs into this, it probably does in fact mean it's a bad address to access.

Comment: "If it's inside an allocation, how is it out of bounds?" Are you saying, it is OK to go beyond the range of an array, as long as you end up in another array nearby? No, it's not. You must stay withing that very same array/allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand the error, because it reports both "Address is out of bounds" and "Address is inside the nearest allocation". If it's inside an allocation, how is it out of bounds?

There is no contradiction here.

It is inside *an* allocation which you made within the current CUDA context. It is not inside *the* allocation you passed to the kernel to operate on.

Comment: I don't think this analysis quite fits the report. The allocation reported starts at `0x7fd8aa000000` and ends at `0x7fd8c8000000-1`. Address 0x7fd8c0000224 thus falls within the only allocation in play here. It seems the access is out of bounds with respect to a specific *data object* within the allocation.